# Converse to common permutation problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

If there is a common permutation matrix $P\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that $A_i=PB_iP'$ holds at $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ where $A_i,B_i\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric then it is true that $\prod_{i=1}^mA_i=P\prod_{i=1}^m B_i P'$ holds.

Is the converse statement stating if $\prod_{i=1}^mA_i=P\prod_{i=1}^m B_i P'$ holds with $P\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ a permutation matrix (chosen outside union of automorphism groups of $A_i$ and $B_i$) and each $A_i,B_i\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric then $P$ is a common permutation matrix such that $A_i=PB_iP'$ holds at each $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ also true?

If not true why?

Is there special restrictions where the converse can hold or can $\prod_{i=1}^m$ be replaced by some other function such that converse can hold?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "chosen outside union of automorphism...". Ignoring that part this is pretty clearly not true though. Consider $A_1 = A_2 = B_1 = B_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Daishisan $A_i$ and $B_i$ are symmetric and so considered as adjacencies of graphs $G_{A_i}$ and $G_{B_i}$ have automorphism group. I want permutation to be outside union of groups for all the involved graphs